# .htaccess does many internal loops

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess

```
#### BOF SSU 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /refm/ 

# Deny access from .htaccess 
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F] 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [E=VAR1:$1,QSA,L] 

#### EOF SSU
```

I've been using the same .htaccess code on Ubuntu and it was working fine, now I'm working on a windows machine and it doesn't seem to work, it always loads the homepage when I click on any on the inside pages. Basically, what this .htaccess does is to enable pretty permalinks for Zen Cart pages and products. The .htaccess file is recognized by Apache as I've checked the `httpd.conf` configurations, I checked `error.log` and here is the error that I found:

`[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

I've also changed the `LogLevel` to `debug` instead of `warn` to see the details of the error and here is what I got:

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3065): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-
type-page-38`

`[Tue Jun 05 23:31:09 2012] [debug] core.c(3071): [client 127.0.0.1] redirected from r->uri = /css/style.css, referer: http://localhost/refm/refm-excel-products-by-property-type-page-38`

So there seems to be some kind of loop. Can you help me figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: Use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` instead of `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}`

Comment: just tried doing this and still having the same issue

Comment: remove `RewriteBase /refm/` and tell me what happens?

Comment: still having the same issue, many redirection loops.

Comment: are you sure `index.php` exists?

Comment: and also use `@Death` to inform me, please!

Comment: @Death, yes i'm sure it exists, the same identical website is hosted locally on Ubuntu and this issue is not happening.

Comment: Try enabling rewritelog in your http.conf, and post what it inside it after a failed request.

Comment: try this:`RewriteRule ^(?<!index\.php).*$ index.php?/$1 [E=VAR1:$1,QSA,L] `

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [E=VAR1:$1,L]
```